# Counting using JOIN in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two sets A and B. I want to display counts of A as well as counts on A (intersection) B using condition X.

[image]

Code I am using

```
SELECT COUNT(A) as total, COUNT(IF (condition_X)) as chg
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON JOIN KEY Y
```

I am able to get the intersection but not the count of A in total.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is "condition X"?  Also, "count on" is not colloquial; do you mean "count of"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want a `cross join`?

```
select *
from (select count(*) as cnt_a from a) a cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt_b
      from a join
           b
           on y
      where condition
     ) b
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply left join the two

```
 Select count(A.id=B.id), 
   count(A.id) 
   from A left join B on A.id=B.id
    where condition='x'
```